# Why is my Vue 3 child component not updating

Tags: vuejs3

When I click on the items I can see them updating in the Vue Chrome plugin. But the HTML does no update. I've read several other similar answers but most of them involved some other aspect of Vue and many claimed that with Vue3 I didn't need to use Vue.$set or something similar in this case.

Parent

```
<template>
...
<item-list :items="items" @toggleCollected="i => items[i].collected = !items[i].collected"></item-list>
</template>
<script setup>
...
let items = ref([])
onMounted(async () => {
  var response = await api.getRoom(game.value, roomName.value)
  ...
  items = response.room.items

  roomHub.joinRoom(game.value, roomName.value)
})
```

Child

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items" @click="$emit('toggleCollected', i)">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
</template>


<script setup>
    const props = defineProps(['items'])
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items.value = response.room.items
```

I was missing a .value. New to Vue 3!

EDIT: const! I should have been using const!